# Cannot delete contributions

Tags: civicontribute

I am trying to delete a contribution and after I confirm that I want to it just hangs with the pop up and a spinning CiviCRM logo indefinitely. I get the following in the error log.

Feb 24 10:07:53  [error] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
[callback] => Array
(
[0] => CRM_Core_Error
[1] => handle
)

```
[code] => -26
[message] => DB Error: insufficient permissions
[mode] => 16
[debug_info] => DELETE FROM civicrm_activity WHERE source_record_id IN ( 3710 ) AND activity_type_id IN ( 6 ) [nativecode=1142 ** TRIGGER command denied to user 'coma6771_crmwp'@'localhost' for table 'civicrm_activity']
[type] => DB_Error
[user_info] => DELETE FROM civicrm_activity WHERE source_record_id IN ( 3710 ) AND activity_type_id IN ( 6 ) [nativecode=1142 ** TRIGGER command denied to user 'coma6771_crmwp'@'localhost' for table 'civicrm_activity']
[to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: insufficient permissions" code=-26 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="DELETE FROM civicrm_activity WHERE source_record_id IN ( 3710 ) AND activity_type_id IN ( 6 ) [nativecode=1142 ** TRIGGER command denied to user 'coma6771_crmwp'@'localhost' for table 'civicrm_activity']"]
```

)

The user has full access for the database, but I can't see anything about table specific access.I know it was working quite recently and don't think I have changed anything relevant.

I'm on WordPress and CiviCRM 5.26.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you move the database with `mysqldump` and `mysql`? Then trigger can fail because he has rights in the old database, and not in the new. The solution is to recreate all triggers. This can be done with the following command.

```
wp eval "Civi::service('sql_triggers')->rebuild(NULL, FALSE);"
```

Comment: Don't understand, but I managed to add SSH access and run this and it solved the problem. Thanks